# IDE for MinGW with SVN support

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010, svn, ide

I would like to compile with `MinGW` on Windows. I am seeking for IDE (Visual Studio 2010 is out, because as far as I know it cannot use `MinGW`) with integrated SVN support like AnkhSVN plugin for Visual Studio 2010. One candidate is `CodeBlocks`. Does it have some SVN plugin? Or would you recommend another IDE? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers.

With the subclipse plugin you have accesses to `svn` as well

Link: http://eclipse.org/downloads/moreinfo/c.php

Answer (score 3):

I use Eclipse with CDT, and SVN integration is very good.

Comment: Thank you, I will try Eclipse but I am maybe looking for something more lightweight than Eclipse IDE.

Answer (score 1):

I'm all for Eclipse CDT, it rocks.

However, you did mention you wanted something more lightweight.

A popular Windows and Linux alternative is Code::Blocks (http://www.codeblocks.org/).

Its a great open source C/C++ IDE and even comes bundled with MinGW.

EDIT:  Also has SVN support, according to http://www.codeblocks.org/downloads/7

Answer (score 1):

You can also try netbeans, most people in my company use it now and they say it's faster than eclipse.

I still use eclipse, but since you don't want it you may want to try netbeans with svn plugin.

Answer (score 1):

try http://qt.nokia.com/products/developer-tools

It was written for Qt but it can also be used for plain C++. Furthermore it has great support for CMake (if you are like me and do not like qmake).

Answer (score 0):

I use Eclipse CDT at our school, the University of Advancing Technology in Tempe AZ.  One of our students put together a package that's an all-in-one version of Eclipse CDT (Helios at the moment.  Indigo real soon now.) + Subclipse + Boost + cppunit. It is targeted at Windows 7 only.  If you wish, you can download this self extracting executable at http://dl.dropbox.com/u/341940/cdt.exe

Answer (score 0):

I'm very partial to CodeLite. You can use it on Windows and Linux. It has support for Subversion, Qt, and wxWidgets.

http://www.codelite.org/Main/ReadMore